# How do I calculate electron acceleration by gravitational waves?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, particle-accelerators

If the amplitude of gravitational waves, frequency of gravitational waves and the vector potential of magnetic field in surrounding of such waves are known then what would be the easiest way to calculate resultant acceleration of electrons? I just want a basic formula to show the resultant electron acceleration.

I actually want to code the equations given on point no.2 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0312151.pdf to give the output of resultant electron acceleration with minimal input. I am finding it really difficult to solve because of unknown parameters in equations and my lack of physics knowledge. Please help

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean with "input of magnetic field"?

Comment: acceleration due to gravity waves? Semantics will cause problems here.

Comment: Yes acceleration of electron by gravity waves @YashasSamaga

Comment: Suggestion - change "If magnetic field, amplitude of gravitational waves and frequency of gravitational waves" to "If the amplitude of gravitational waves and frequency of gravitational waves.." - I would edit myself, but I think the OP should edit it or leave it alone.

Comment: uhm, NOob94, unless you're hanging around the event horizon of a black hole, the acceleration of an electron due to gravity waves is far, far, far less than any interaction due to electromagnetic sources or quantum mechanics.  seems like a pretty bizarre concept, unless it's meant to be around some place where gravity waves are obscenely intense.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson    I just want to calculate in a simulated event where there is a magnetic equilibrium present.